# navigationController with NavigationBarHidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am calling SearchViewController like this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:SearchViewController animated:YES];
```

In the SearchViewController I don't want Navigation Bar, I want to hide it completely, can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing/hiding navigation bar with smooth animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079590/showing-hiding-navigation-bar-with-smooth-animation)

Comment: I tried that, but it is not working       [self.navigationController pushViewController: SearchViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Comment: I hope you are calling that line of code in SearchViewController i.e. the view controller where you want to hide it when it loads like in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Thanks Jaideep, now it works :) thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Hide the navigation bar :

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

to Show the navigation bar :

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

I'd suggest go through documenation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html), its a good read.

Hope this helps !